# VBA- Search for duplicates and sum them

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following sheet as an example:
[Example of how the sheet can look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dksGS.png)
I need a language that searches the entire A column and when it finds duplicates of the same account such as 167, it sums all the account values (from D and E) with the same account number in column F (for Column D) and G (for Column E). It would be great if the sum could be found in the last cell of the last account from the duplicates. In the case of 167 that would mean F/G10.

P.S. If i were to also delete the previous rows after summing them (keeping only the last one with the sum), how could i do that?

Thank you! Great answers!

Comment: Use a pivot table or `SumIf`. For the latter of the two you can also get the unique records using Advanced Data Filter.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies! Awesome community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For a formula solution:**

Put this in Cell `F2` and fill down:

`=IF(COUNTIF(A3:$A$17,A2)>0,"",SUMIF(A:A,A2,D:D))`

Put this in Cell `G2` and fill down:

`=IF(COUNTIF(A3:$A$17,A2)>0,"",SUMIF(A:A,A2,E:E))`

Assuming your dataset goes past the screenshot you will need to change `$A$17` in the `COUNTIF` to match the row after the last row of data.

**For a VBA solution:**

This will do the calculations for you and only populate the values of the results:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim j As String

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For i = 2 To lRow

j = .Evaluate("=IF(COUNTIF(A" & i + 1 & ":$A$" & lRow + 1 & ",A" & i & ")>0,"""",SUMIF(A:A,A" & i & ",D:D))")

.Cells(i, 6).Value = j

Next i

For i = 2 To lRow

j = .Evaluate("=IF(COUNTIF(A" & i + 1 & ":$A$" & lRow + 1 & ",A" & i & ")>0,"""",SUMIF(A:A,A" & i & ",E:E))")

.Cells(i, 7).Value = j

Next i

End With

End Sub
```

This will paste the formulas in their respective cells, but will keep the formulas there:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lRow As Integer

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For i = 2 To lRow

.Cells(i, 6).Value = "=IF(COUNTIF(A" & i + 1 & ":$A$" & lRow + 1 & ",A" & i & ")>0,"""",SUMIF(A:A,A" & i & ",D:D))"

Next i

For i = 2 To lRow

.Cells(i, 7).Value = "=IF(COUNTIF(A" & i + 1 & ":$A$" & lRow + 1 & ",A" & i & ")>0,"""",SUMIF(A:A,A" & i & ",E:E))"

Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative VBA solutions

with formulas

```
Sub Test_KeepFormulas()    
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(, 5).Resize(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(R[+1]C1:R20C1, RC1)>0,"""",SUMIF(C1,RC1,C[-2]))"    
End Sub
```

with values

```
Sub Test_KeepValues()    
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(, 5).Resize(, 2)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(R[+1]C1:R20C1, RC1)>0,"""",SUMIF(C1,RC1,C[-2]))"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```